# Is it expensive to read properties from window object?

Tags: javascript, web-performance

For example, let's say we have two versions of lazyload (see code below). In terms of performance, is versionII better than version I?

```
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img'); 
window.addEventListener('scroll' , lazyload);

// version I 
function lazyload() { 
  imgs.forEach((img) => { 
    if (img.offsetTop < window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) { 
      img.src = img.dataset.src; 
    }
  }
}

// version II
function lazyload() { 
  const innerHeight = window.innerHeight; 
  const pageYOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
  imgs.forEach((img) => { 
    if (img.offsetTop < innerHeight + pageYOffset) { 
    img.src = img.dataset.src; 
  }
}
```

Comment: This screams premature optimization. Are you sure it actually matters if one is faster?

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Xin! Your question is a good one and, I think, very important. I suspect the down-votes are because of the code as image, which is now fixed. Please don't be discouraged from asking and answering.  :-)

Comment: Thank you Michael! You are so kind~@MichaelCrenshaw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your specific question:

I'll rephrase your *specific* question like this:

> Is it costly to access `window.innerHeight` and/or `window.pageYOffset`?

It can be. According to [Paul Irish of the Google Chrome Developer Tooling team](https://www.paulirish.com/about/):

> All of the below properties or methods, when requested/called in JavaScript, will trigger the browser to synchronously calculate the style and layout*. This is also called reflow or [layout thrashing](http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/), and **is common performance bottleneck**.
>
> ...
>
> **window**
>
> ```
> window
> window.scrollX, window.scrollY
> window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth
> window.getMatchedCSSRules() only forces style
> ```

-- [What forces layout / reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) (emphasis mine)

At the [bottom of that document](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a#appendix), Paul indicates the layout reflow will only occur under certain circumstances. The portions below (with my added emphasis) answer your question better and more authoritatively than I could.

> - **Reflow only has a cost if the document has changed** and invalidated    the style or layout. Typically, this is because the DOM was changed (classes modified, nodes added/removed, even adding a psuedo-class like :focus).
> - If layout is forced, style must be recalculated first.    So forced layout triggers both operations. **Their costs are very    dependent on the content/situation**, but typically both operations are    similar in cost.
> - What should you do about all this? Well, the More on    forced layout section below covers everything in more detail, but the
>     short version is:
>
>   1. `for` **loops that force layout & change the DOM are    the worst**, avoid them.
>   2. **Use DevTools Timeline to see where this    happens**. You may be surprised to see how often your app code and    library code hits this.
>   3. Batch your writes & reads to the DOM (via    [FastDOM](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom) or a virtual DOM implementation). Read your metrics at the    begininng of the frame (very very start of rAF, scroll handler, etc),    when the numbers are still identical to the last time layout was    done.

Changing the `src` attribute is probably sufficient to "invalidate the style or layout." (Although I suspect using something like [correctly-dimensioned SVG placeholders for lazy-loaded images](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-content-reflow-from-lazy-loaded-images/) would mitigate or eliminate the cost of the reflows.)

In short, your "version I" implementation is preferable and has, as far as I can tell, no real disadvantages.

## Your general question

As shown above, reading properties from the window object *can* be expensive. But others are right to point out a couple things:

1. Optimizing too early or too aggressively can cost you valuable time, energy, and (depending on your solution) maintainability.
2. The only way to be certain is to test. Try both versions of your code, and carefully analyze your favorite dev tool's output for performance differences.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems better

```
// version III
function lazyload(){
  const dimension = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset;
  img.array.forEach(img => {
    if (img.offsetTop < dimension) {
      img.src = img.dataset.src;
    }
  });
}
```